# Forwarding Boost MSM events to a submachine

Tags: c++, events, boost, state-machine

I have a Main FSM with submachine SubA. All I want to do is forward an event from Main to SubA.

Main:

```
initial_state=Initial
Row< Initial, Event1, SubA, none, none >
```

SubA:

```
initial_state=State1
Row< State1, Event1, State2, Action1, none >
```

```
Main.process_event(Event1);
```

SubA State1 gets `on_entry` but never transitions from State1 to State2 or triggers associated Action1 as indicated in table. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here is some documents about sub-machine state events. http://redboltz.wikidot.com/entry-point-pseudo-state

Comment: Pseudo state solution didn't work for me because I want my submachines to independently hold their own state. I don't want to pass state control using pseudo entry/exit between the parent and submachines.

Comment: In your example, Event1 is consumed by outer transition. You need to process_event(Event1) once more. Then State1 to State2 transition would occur.

Comment: Worked. Much thanks. Also, when I added the sub-machines in the Main initial state (typedef mpl::vector<Sub1, Sub2> initial_state;) events were forwarded to all sub-machines, which is what I wanted.

Comment: Maybe you already know, typedef mpl::vector<Sub1, Sub2> initial_state means orthogonal regions.
  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/ch03s02.html#d0e577

Comment: When using orthogonal regions I'm having trouble getting the current state of a region. main_fsm.current_state()[n] never reflects the actual state of a region.

Comment: Using typedef int activate_deferred_events fixed current state retrieval. Thanks.